# React native(0.67.3) Image.getSize() Failed in iOS(16.5.1)

Tags: ios, react-native

"Recently, we received user feedback about an error in fetching images. The error message is as follows:"
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSYrk.png)

[system info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1GZO.png)

Upon investigation, it was found that "In order to adapt the image, we used Image.getSize() to retrieve the width and height ratio of the remote image, but it failed and threw an error."

React Native Version(0.67.3)

Troubleshooting:

- The latest iOS version 16.6 displays images correctly.
- There are no reported issues on Android.

How to resolve the problem?

1. Currently, it seems that users are unable to update to the latest iOS version. Should we provide some compatibility adjustments and release a new version?
2. Can we assist users in upgrading their versions?

"I hope to receive some assistance."

Comment: For some unknown reason, it is working again.